# How can I center 3 images inline w/ bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As I've been cranking out one page webapps for my javascript class, I thought it'd be a neat idea to throw together a place to store them and link them all.

Similar to android or ios I have a page with several icons for links to the apps. I've been able to center them as I'd like, but I've run into a bit of a snag. The problem I'm facing is how I go around scaling them correctly. I do not wish to have them span the entire webpage.

Currently my html looks as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content col-xs-4">
            <a href="./flickr" class="img responsive"> <img alt="Flickr" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;" src="css/img/flickr.png" data-holder-rendered="true"> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content col-xs-4">
            <a href="./notepad" class="img responsive"> <img alt="Notepad" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;" src="css/img/notepad.png" data-holder-rendered="true"> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content col-xs-4">
            <a href="http://aug.ie" class="img responsive"> <img alt="Url Shortener" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;" src="css/img/link.png" data-holder-rendered="true"> </a>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

In the future if and when I create more apps, I'd like to have a fairly easy time of adding an icon and link to it on this page. Does bootstrap contain a method of resizing columns, or should I perhaps resize the row?

I'm in unfamiliar territory at the moment so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you use this:

```
style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;"
```

It is redundant, since bootstrap does this out of the box with the `img-responsive` class. But in your code example you have written: `img responsive` instead of `img-responsive`

You said that :

> I do not wish to have them span the entire webpage.

if you use `container` it contains all items inside a 12 column grid. if you use `container-fluid` it spans the entire webpage.

In my example i used col-sm-4 . Which will put 3 columns inline as long as your page is 768px and up. If you would like to have 3 columns on mobile phones and up use col-xs-4 . But always make sure you get 12 in total.

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content col-sm-4">
                <a href="./flickr" class="img-responsive"> <img alt="Flickr"  src="css/img/flickr.png" data-holder-rendered="true"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="content col-sm-4">
                <a href="./notepad" class="img-responsive"> <img alt="Notepad"  src="css/img/notepad.png" data-holder-rendered="true"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="content col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://aug.ie" class="img-responsive"> <img alt="Url Shortener"  src="css/img/link.png" data-holder-rendered="true"> </a>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have a custom class called img that increases the size on hover. Thank you for this valuable insight though. I in addition wasn't sure why I was using some of the classes that I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one :

```css
.row li {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

img {
  border: 0 none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="small-img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 center">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive inline-block" alt="Responsive image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive inline-block" alt="Responsive image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive inline-block" alt="Responsive image" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer as well?